# VSIX: Adding Projects with Roslyn refactoring options says "Not supported"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, roslyn, visual-studio-extensions, roslyn-code-analysis

I feel like there should be an easy way to do this. I mean it can't be possible that you can't add projects via extensions?

What I want to do:

I want to write a small extension that adds a "code refactoring" option to methods that will generate a test class and method for it in the matching test project. If the test project does not exist, I will create it.

Everything is working so far, except that when I try to use `Solution.AddProject()` it throws the exception `System.NotSupportedException : Adding projects is not supported.`.
Feels like the active workspace does not allow adding projects to it. I've read something about `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CustomWorkspace` but it does not work. And `AdhocWorkspace` does not persist any changes, right?

My code (simplified) so far:

```
private static async Task<Solution> CreateTest(Document document, MethodDeclarationSyntax method, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var solution = document.Project.Solution;

    // Try to find existing test project
    var projectName = document.Project.Name + ".UnitTests";
    var testProject = solution.Projects.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == projectName);
    if (testProject == null)
    {
        // Create the project and update the solution
        testProject = solution.AddProject(projectName, projectName, LanguageNames.CSharp); // <----- THIS IS FAILING
        solution = testProject.Solution;
    }

    // Try to find existing test document
    var documentName = $"{((TypeDeclarationSyntax) method.Parent).Identifier.Text}Tests.cs";
    var testDocument = testProject.Documents.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == documentName);

    if (testDocument == null)
    {
        // Create the document and update the project and solution
        testDocument = testProject.AddDocument(documentName, "", document.Folders);
        testProject = testDocument.Project;
        solution = testProject.Solution;
    }

    return solution;
}
```

The preview of Roslyn code changes does work correct and says it will add the correct project. When I click it, the following exception occurs

```
System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. ---> Adding projects is not supported.
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Suggestions.SuggestedAction.InvokeWorker(Func`1 getFromDocument,IProgressTracker progressTracker,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Suggestions.SuggestedAction.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<InvokeCore>b__0()
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Extensions.IExtensionManagerExtensions.PerformAction(IExtensionManager extensionManager,Object extension,Action action)
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.NotSupportedException : Adding projects is not supported.
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace.CheckAllowedSolutionChanges(SolutionChanges solutionChanges)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspace.TryApplyChanges(Solution newSolution,IProgressTracker progressTracker)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.ProjectSystem.VisualStudioWorkspaceImpl.TryApplyChanges(Solution newSolution,IProgressTracker progressTracker)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CodeActions.ApplyChangesOperation.TryApply(Workspace workspace,IProgressTracker progressTracker,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.CodeActions.CodeActionEditHandlerService.ProcessOperations(Workspace workspace,ImmutableArray`1 operations,IProgressTracker progressTracker,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at async Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.CodeActions.CodeActionEditHandlerService.ApplyAsync(<Unknown Parameters>)<---
```

So I guess `ApplyChangesKind.AddProject` is set to `false` for the workspace.

What's the way to fix this? Or the correct way to add projects with Roslyn?

For all who want to test it the quick way I have included the full code:
https://gist.github.com/Wolfsblvt/1420c4ddd11f9386cb3ab2dadff313cb

Comment: This is because new projects must be added through VS APIs.

Comment: @SLaks: Isn't that what I am using? Or do you mean you can't add it through Roslyn? What would the correct way be then to add a project via VS API?

Comment: Please check the version of Roslyn, and upgrade to the latest version (right click project -> Manage NuGet Packages.. -> Installed -> select Microsft.CodeAnalysis -> update) and check if it works for you.

Comment: @ColeWu-MSFT: I have all NuGet packages up to date. Microsoft.CodeAnalysis is on 2.1.0, latest stable. That's the setup I have tested it with. http://i.imgur.com/QIhdcEB.png

Comment: @Wolfsblvt: please check the reply comment of Jason Malinowski, it seems that roslyn haven't implemented the funcation. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36135604/how-add-existing-project-to-c-sharp-solution-with-roslyn, if you want to use visual studio sdk to implements it, which need the template file. for more information, please refer to: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228774.aspx